# How to control the size of a picture using tkinter?

Tags: image, python-3.x, canvas, tkinter

I want to control the size of the picture in `m_image` (say, I want it to be 420x380).
How do I do that?

```
import tkinter as tk

m_gui = tk.Tk()
m_image = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'pic.gif')
m_canvas = tk.Canvas(m_gui)
m_canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = m_image)
m_canvas.pack()

m_gui.mainloop()
```

It would be great if you could also give an explanation about the first two parameters of the `create_image` func.

Thank you

Comment: It's the position - see http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_image-method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tk is a gui framework, not an image manipulation program.  Two solutions:

1. Use an external image manipulation program to create a .bmp, .gif, or (if using tcl/tk 8.6) .png file with the size you want.
2. Install pillow (`pip install pillow` worked for me), use it to do the needed [image manipulation](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), and use its [ImageTk module](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/ImageTk.html) to "create and modify Tkinter BitmapImage and PhotoImage objects from PIL images".